# C#.Net inherit from a child of Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, master-pages

I'm trying to build a basic abstract class for all my master's content pages:

```
/// <summary>
/// Basic class for Show pages
/// </summary>
public abstract partial class BasicShowForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The project currently showing in the master
    /// </summary>
    public Project project;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the master that currently running
        this.project = ((ShowMaster)Master).Project;
    }    
}
```

but when i'm trying to extend it in a new page it can't find the class:

[image]

What do i need to do i order to make it work ?

Comment: Do you want to make masterpage? or a basic page??

Comment: i have masterpage and this is his content.. i gonna have lots of pages as contents, and i wanted to create a basic page for loading all the details i need in order to avoid code re-writting

Comment: Move the class to your App_Code folder

Comment: its a web site not a web application, and its a form - its not supposed to be there